# Pure javascript/importable library/script to minify HTML in a function

Tags: javascript, html, minify

I haven't found an independent library or function that will allow me to minify HTML while preserving proper formatting. There's a bunch of online minifiers that do the job, but I really need something that I can just include in a function on click or something along those lines.

I really like what http://minifycode.com/html-minifier/ does, I would like to find a way to mimic or replicate this.

I'll keep looking, if you guys can help I'll be so grateful!

Comment: Did you consider separating your files ? One formatted version to work on, one fully minimified only for production.

Comment: yes, good point. This is a client-side asynchronous thing that happens. So I need a text field or selection to be minified before playing with it.

Comment: generally while development you should never minify for debugging purposes, it should always be the production code which is uglified and minified be it css, js or in your case html.